# Editor can't find PyQt?/ Trouble with import

Tags: pydev

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 with Python 2.3.0 on a Kubuntu system. I was using Python 2.x before and am now trying to start a new project in Python 3.2. I didn't have any trouble in Python 2.x and did not encounter any problems installing PyQt's packages for python3.

When I'm writing a PyQt-app in Python 3.x the code completion isn't working and there are error messages shown in the editor. When importing with "from PyQt4.QtCore import *" the error messages appear where I'm using PyQt's names (e.g. "app = QApplication(sys.argv)", there is however no error message in the import statement itself. When importing via "import PyQt4.QtCore" there will be an error message at the import statement, but not when using the imported names (e.g. app = PyQt.QtCore.QApplication(sys.argv)". Code completion will still not be working.

The code executes without errors, widgets are shown. "PYQT_VERSION_STR", "platform.system()" etc. result in Python Version 3.2.3, Qt Version 4.8.1, PyQt Version 4.9.1, System Linux. PyDev's package explorer shows a "python3" tree node (= the PYTHONPATH?) and as its children e.g. System Libs -> python3/dist-packages -> PyQt 4 -> QtCore.cpython-32mu.so

I removed and added the interpreter in PyDev's config several times and/ or clicked "apply" in various combinations, with no success. I started a new test project afterwards, the problems were still there. I was not able to locate "interpreterInfo.py" through a file system search. Sample code: http://pastebin.com/niDLRy9i

Any help is appreciated :-)